# Keyboard stops working after login

Tags: keyboard, 19.10

My laptop keyboard (and any keyboard I plug in) stops working after I sign in. I'm not sure what the issue is. Has anyone encountered an issue like this?

I'm running Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: Boot from a LiveUSB on that PC; does the problem persist? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 1):

If your keyboard is working during log in, then most probably your Desktop Environment configuration is somehow broken.

To resolve this you could try the next:

- Switch to tty: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>
- `adduser username` # create a new user
- `usermod -aG sudo username` # add it into the `sudo` group
- Log in using the new user and check
- Install different Desktop Environment (choose one or a few):

  - `sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop`
  - `sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-desktop^`
  - `sudo apt install budgie-desktop`
- Switch to different Display manager (lightdm, gdm, lxdm, kdm, xdm, etc., but install it first if not installed by `sudo apt install lxdm`):

  - `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`